If $X$ is a continuous supermartingale, why is, for every $N$, $(X_s)_{s\leq N}$ uniformly integrable?

If $X$ is a continuous supermartingale, why is, for every $N$, $(X_s)_{s\leq N}$ uniformly integrable?

This statement is used, without proof, in another statement. I haven't been able to prove it. Is it an easy argument? Or does it need some work?

I have doubts about this assertion. (Where did you read it?)
Example. Let $(B_t)$ be a standard 1-dimensional Brownian motion (with $B_0=0$). Let $Z_t:=\exp(B_t-t/2)$ be the corresponding geometric Brownian motion. This is a positive martingale, but $\lim_{t\to\infty}Z_t=0$ a.s., so $(Z_t)$ is not uniformly integrable. Finally, define $X_t:=Z_{t/(1-t)}$ for $0\le t<1$ and $:=0$ for $t\ge 1$.  Then $(X_t)$ is a continuous non-negative supermartingale; in particular, $(X_t)_{0\le t\le 1}$ is a supermartingale, but it is not uniformly integrable.

Hey, thanks. I read it in Klenke's "Probability Theory" 2nd. ed., p. 473, second paragraph.

By substituting $X'_t:=X_t-E[X_N|\mathcal F_t]$ for $X_t$ one can reduce the the situation in which $X_t\ge 0$. (The martingale term $E[X_N|\mathcal F_t]$ is uniformly integrable). When $X_t$ is non-negative, Klenke's appeal to (suspect) uniform integrability can be replaced by an application of Fatou's lemma.

Very helpful, thank you.
